# Can I set a saved report or shortcut as the default Google Analytics home page?

Tags: google-analytics

By default, `http://analytics.google.com` comes to the Home dashboard, that can also be found here:

[image]

**Is there a way to set a "Saved report" or "Shortcut" as default home page for analytics when going to `http://analytics.google.com`?**

(I know I can bookmark a shortcut, but here I'd like to know if modifying default Home is possible).